# text field wont display numbers and uppercase letters in flash, how to?

Tags: flash, numbers, actionscript-2, textfield, movieclip

i have a bit of a wired problem.

i have a flash movie clip called `PWD`. inside it i have a dynamic text / classic text field called `ATF`.

i am trying to load some text into it but it cent seem to load uppercase letters or numbers.

```
PWD.ATF.htmlText = "username: <font color = \'#FFFFFF\'> " + _root.xDATA.username + " </font>
```

so if the `username` is `Example123` i can only see `xample`

i am using AS2.

any ideas?

edit:

even if i hard code some numbers they still don't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you use font with small letters only, or you use embed font with only small letters there